# Firebase structure data levels

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My web app stores user's data and their transactions to the corresponding bank institution (item). My data structure looks like this:

```
users
  ---->items
        item_id
        ---->accounts
                 ----->transactions
```

The problem:

I have a webhook which accepts notifications from a third party server if transactions are ready to pull. The response contains **item_id**, so I have to pull the user which has an **item_id** = to incoming **item_id** and **Frank van Puffelen** said that "**Firebase Database queries can only sort on a property one level deep or in a fixed path**", therefore i'm forced to change the structure of my data.

One of the possible structures is this:

```
users
  uid
items
  uid
  item_id
  ---->accounts
          ---->transactions
```

So, creating a new item with **uid** which refers to the user's request to create that particular item, then using **item_id** to get the **uid** of the user.

**My question:** Is this feasible solution when dealing with 1mil+ users, or is there any workaround to deal with my old structure?

Comment: Assuming that `item_id` is unique, and that `item_id` can only be ever held by a single `user`, then you can use your original setup, plus a reverse-lookup table of  `{ item_id : uid }`.  Then the webhook transaction comes in, reverse lookup the uid, grab the user branch and then work with your original setup.

Comment: A user gets an item_id when connecting to a bank institution. item_id is unique for each institution and for each user. User A is linked to Chase bank with item_id 100 and  to Bank of America with item_id 200, similarly User B is linked to these two banks but with item_id 300 and 400

Comment: Great!  So just use reverse-lookup table `{ item_id : uid }`.